# Can anyone recommend a website or other sources that can evaluate my essays and offer feedback

Tags: resources, essay

I want some professional or expert to review my essays and offer me feedback on how can I improve, things I could to do write better, tell me mistakes, etc. and inspire the examiner to award me more marks.

Comment: We have a whole list of feedback/critique sites [here on our site Meta](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/925/where-can-i-get-a-critique-of-my-work), but it doesn't say whether any of them accept essay critiques, so I don't feel comfortable making an answer out of it.

Comment: @rolfedh That doesn't make it off-topic; questions asking for off-site resources are allowed here. We just have to keep a watchful eye on the answers to ensure they a) explain how the linked resource will be useful, and b) disclose any affiliation with said resource.

Comment: Also see https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/48740/where-can-i-go-to-have-my-writing-reviewed-both-in-terms-of-style-and-technical

Comment: @rolfedh Good find. I think that would make this a duplicate.

Comment: @F1Krazy That meta topic is excellent. I'm guessing the previous moderator community created it to handle exactly this type of question.